Non-zero coprime solutions to $x^2 + y^3 = 2^n$
Consider the diophantine equation $x^2 + y^3 = 2^n$, where $x,y$ are non-zero coprime integers and $n$ is a positive integer.
This is a special case of the Fermat-Catalan equation.
I am wondering is there any results about the non-zero coprime solutions of this equation?

In 2014, Z. Zhang and J. G. Luo. https://actamath.cjoe.ac.cn/Jwk_sxxb_cn/EN/10.12386/A2014sxxb0020 solved the Diophantine equation $x^2 + By^{2p} = z^3$ for some values of $B$ inclusing $B=2^n$ for $n\geq 6$. With $y=1$, this reduces to $z^3-x^2=2^n$, which is your equation up to sign.

A simpler approach is to let $r = n \bmod 6$ and divide both sides by $2^{n-r}$. Setting $Y = x/2^{(n-r)/2}$, $X = -y/2^{(n-r)/3}$ yields a rational point on the elliptic curve $Y^{2} = X^{3} + 2^{r}$ where the denominator of $x$ and $y$ are both powers of $2$. There are only finitely many such rational points and they can be found fairly easily with existing software.
